# python3 : Cannot import name flask

Tags: python, flask

I tried the following simple code,

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

it is running fine with,

```
python hello.py
```

but it gives an error when i try with python3

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A package is installed against a specific Python version/location.  Installing Flask for Python 2 (which is probably what the `python` and `pip` commands are aliased to), doesn't install it for Python 3.

You should really just use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html) to control exactly what versions and packages you are using.

This creates a Python 3 environment and installs Flask:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 my_py3_env
source my_py3_env/bin/activate
pip install flask
```

When you open a new terminal, just source the activate script again to keep using the environment.