# Basic Flask Issue w/ Importing

Tags: python, flask

I'm following a Flask tutorial and am getting an import error.  I have a file called `run.py` which contains:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

When I run `./run.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/myName/Desktop/SquashScraper/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

This seems similar to this issue: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960235/python3-cannot-import-name-flask`

So I attempted the checked solution by running:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 my_py3_env
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
The executable /usr/bin/python3 (from --python=/usr/bin/python3) does not exist
```

Any ideas what may be happening here?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: Which version(s) of Python do you have installed on the system and which is executed with `python -V`?

Comment: @Wyrmwood this one: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: @Celeo I have 2.7 and 3.3.  When I run python -V, I get "Python 3.3.3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your virtual environment to be Python 3 but don't know the installation directory, use `which python3`. Use that directory in your `virtualenv -p [directory] my_py3_env` command to set up the Python 3 virtual environment.

I sounds like your pip is installing to your Python 2.X directory. If you're okay with that, you'll need to run the app either with `python2 run.py`, `python2.X run.py` where `x` is your installed version, or change the symlink of `python` in `/usr/bin/python` to your installation of Python 2.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions) question has some more information.

Regardless of the version of Python that you wish to use, you will need to install Flask to *that* version of Python. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/how-to-pip-install-to-specific-version-of-python) question for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I do what you suggest and now when I run ./run.py, I get "Import Error: cannot import name Flask"...thanks again!